How to set up multiple Docker sub networks locally on MiniKube
I am trying to emulate a multiple-bank environment with a clearing house for a research topic. Each bank has a set of Spring Boot Microservices like API Gateway, transaction service, account service etc that will handle customer registrations and transactions.
For cross-banking transaction there is a clearing house service that redirects requests to appropriate banks identified by a routing number.
I want to test this system locally using Jmeter to ping individual services and measure metrics etc.
I have thought of hosting it on MiniKube using Docker Images, but I am not able to figure out the best way to do it and how will the docker images communicate with each other if hosted locally.
Do I need Multiple MiniKube instances with each bank microservice collection separate on each instance?
If I am thinking on the wrong direction,what will be the optimum solution be?
Here is a sample architecture of the Bank microservice service group:
UML Diagram
The structure is kept very simple so that it easy to test.

Are you trying to set up multiple (local) Kubernetes clusters?  What is your programming-related question; do you have any particular application source code you're working with?  Kubernetes doesn't have multiple networks and the various Kubernetes-on-Docker setups tend to have their own Kubernetes CNI layer, so manually creating Docker networks won't make a difference.

@DavidMaze I was looking for a solution that would let me emulate a real life situation where three separate banks are interacting with each other, so if multiple (local) kubernetes clusters is the answer then i would go for it and my programming question then would be how to set it up and what configurations do i need to set?
If multiple kubernetes isn't a viable solution then what would be an ideal alternate solution?
